# How do I resolve calls from node.js to HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am currently working with an `app.js file`, I am requiring express, and I am trying to use faker. It compiles and runs, but when I call my faker data to HTML, nothing is loaded. I have tried many things, but it doesn't seem to want to output it.
This is a project for my internet programming class, I am supposed to use a different package from express, and was thinking of using faker, but I can't seem to get it to work, when I add the file, it shows it to me on the local host, but then when I try and display any information, there is nothing showing, it could be because I am trying to mix files?

This is the Code

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
var faker = require("faker");

//routes for the pages
app.get("/", function(req,res){
    res.render("index.html");
});

app.get("/about", function(req,res){
    res.render("about.html");
});

app.get("/services", function(req,res){
    res.render("services.html");
});

app.get("/specs", function(req,res){
    res.render("specs.html");
});

var data = {
    name: faker.name.findName(),
    lastName : faker.name.lastName(),
    jobTitle : faker.name.jobTitle(),
    prefix: faker.name.prefix(),
    suffix: faker.name.suffix(),
    jobArea: faker.name.jobArea(),
    phone: faker.phone.phoneNumber()
}

app.get("/contact", function(req, res){
    res.render('contact' ,{data: data});
    
});

app.use(function(req,res,next){
    res.status(404).send("sorry can't find that");
});

// server.listener
app.listen("8080","127.0.0.1", function(){
    console.log("Express Server is operational ...");
});

// app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, function(){
//  console.log("Express Server operational ...")
// });
```

**ejs**

```
<%- include('partials/header.ejs') %>
<div id="wrapper">
    <h1> Contact Info</h1>
    <table>
        <tbody>  
            <% for(var i=0; i< data.length; i++) {%>  
            <tr>  
                <td>  
                <%=data[i].name %>    
                </td>  
                <td>  
                <%= data[i].lastname%>    
                </td>  
                <td>  
                <%= data[i].phonenumber%>    
                </td>  
                <td>  
                <%= data[i].city%>    
                </td>  
                <td>  
                <%= data[i].state%>    
                </td>  
                <td>  
                <%= data[i].country%>    
                </td>  
            </tr>  
            <% } %>  
        </tbody>  
    </table>
</div>
<%- include('partials/footer.ejs') %>
```

Comment: You are using `ejs` or `HTML`?

Comment: I am trying to pass this to an html file

Comment: In `.html` extension how can you write `ejs` tags?

Comment: well, I was trying but from the Looks of it, I won't be able to do it, should I change my file. to .ejs file?

Comment: Yes just change that `HTML` to the extension of `ejs` and `res.render('contact')` It will work else if want to server `HTML` file you need to write it as `res.sendfile(path.join(__dirname+ '/contact.html')`

Comment: thank you, and should I still pass the {data: data} in the send file ?

Comment: Only if you want to access the data and show in the `ejs` file to render no need to pass `{data:data}`

Comment: I tried changeing the file to ejs, and still won't load anything on the page, i. might be doing something wrong

Comment: Did you write `/contact` in your routes? Or you can update the question

Comment: I just added updates the question

Comment: Please post your full code including your `root` file or you can share your code via `github`